# PropertyValueFactory JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I want to create a table view in Javafx.

`UploaderColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("Uploader Name"));`

For what should be the String parameter where I added `"Uploader Name"` used for? In my case I added the text of the column from my fxml file. It seems to be wrong since I get the following error:

`WARNING: Can not retrieve property 'Uploader Name' in PropertyValueFactory:`

Comment: I don't think property names can have a space in them.

Comment: Don’t use `PropertyValueFactory`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/72437983/2189127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a JavaFX property name in the quotes, instead of `"Uploader Name"`.

So say you change your line to read:

```java
UploaderColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("uploaderName"));
```

Then, in your `User` class, you'd need a property method called `uploaderNameProperty()`.

If no such method is defined, the factory will try to use the bean methods `getUploaderName()` and `setUploaderName()`.

This is described in length here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm#CJAGAAEE

Comment: But also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/72437983/2189127