# Sorting ObservableList in javaFX by String Date

Tags: java, string, list, javafx, arraylist

I have a String containing a Date in the form "dd-MM-yyyy" I want the dates to be sorted when displayed in the table view.

**Controller Class**

```
private final ObservableList<Stock>stockList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
public class StocksController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Stock, String> date;

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle){
        addToCSV.setOnAction(event -> {
            try {
                writeCSV();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
        dollarButton.setOnAction(event -> {changeDollar();});
        percentButton.setOnAction(event -> {changePercent();});
        price.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));
        date.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("dateRN"));
        checker.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("checker"));
        stockView.setItems(stockList);
        search();
        readCSV();
    }
    public void writeCSV() throws IOException {
        String stockNames = ("$" + stockName.getText()).trim().toUpperCase();
        Double stockPrices = Double.parseDouble((stockPrice.getText()).trim());
        String stockDates = stockDate.getValue().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("src/stocks.csv",true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
        pw.println(stockNames + ',' + stockDates + ',' + stockPrices);
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        stockList.clear();
        readCSV();
    }
    public void readCSV(){
        String csv;
        csv = "src/stocks.csv";
        String delimiter = ",";
        try{
            System.out.println(new FileReader(csv));
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csv));
            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] values = line.split(delimiter);
                String stockNames = values[0];
                String stockDates = values[1];
                Double stockPrices = Double.parseDouble(values[2]);
                Stock stock = new Stock(stockNames, stockPrices,stockDates);
                stockList.add(stock);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StocksController.class.getName())
                    .log(Level.FINE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StocksController.class.getName())
                    .log(Level.FINE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**Stock Class**

```
public class Stock {
    private String dateRN;

    public Stock(){
        this.dateRN = "";
    }
    public Stock(String ticker, Double price, String dateRN){
        this.ticker = ticker;
        this.price = price;
        this.dateRN = dateRN;
        this.checker = new CheckBox();
    }
    public String getDateRN() {
        return dateRN;
    }
    public void setDateRN(String dateRN) {
        this.dateRN = dateRN;
    }
}
```

I've tried creating a comparator for Stock but it's not working so I gave up on that method is there anyway I could just create a function inside my controller sorting it directly from the observableList itself? or even when I read in the CSV?

[image: This is how it looks right now, however, I want the dates to be sorted]

Comment: Are you sure you want to store the dates as string as opposed to `LocalDate` or similar?

Comment: I don’t see where stockList is declared.  It is usually good to provide a [mcve] so the issue can be replicated via copy/paste without change.  You can just provide some dummy data, rather than csv as that is irrelevant, but it should compile, you provide fxml if relevant or just a Java app if that is all that is needed, but then it shouldn’t use fxml at all.

Comment: You shouldn’t put nodes like check boxes in your model objects, it will cause problems especially if you put them in a table.

Comment: Wrap your list in a [SortedList](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.base/javafx/collections/transformation/SortedList.html).  Use a LocalDate or Instant to represent the date.  Use a cell factory to render the local date or instant using the format you need.  Similarly for the checkbox, use a CheckBoxTableCell backed by a BooleanProperty in the model.

Comment: @jewelsea I had no issues with the checkboxes however I did need to place them in the table as I need the ability to choose ONLY two rows and compare there prices

Comment: @jewelsea I'm a bit confused on your solution to the problem. I'll try getting done what I understood. Also as per your suggestion I included the stockList declaration I must have missed it when adding the code, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: For further info on sorted lists applied to TableViews and cell factories, see the [TableView](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) does documentation. [makery also provide a tutorial](https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/).

Comment: I don't see anything in your snippets related to sorting (on the other hand: reading and writing data is completely unrelated) - as already suggested by @jewelsea, [mcve] please (also follow the other advices, f.i. it's __wrong__ to add nodes as data)

Comment: Where did the `Stock` class come from? It cannot be compiled.

Answer (score 2):

The application class, `StockTable`

```java
import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StockTable extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        URL url = getClass().getResource("stoktabl.fxml");
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(url);
        BorderPane root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

The FXML file, `stoktabl.fxml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="jfxtests.StocksController">
    <center>
        <TableView fx:id="table">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="dateColumn" text="Date">
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn fx:id="priceColumn" text="Price">
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn fx:id="checkBoxColumn" text="Check Box">
                </TableColumn>
            </columns>
        </TableView>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

FXML controller class, `StocksController`

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class StocksController extends StringConverter<LocalDate> {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter  FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    private static final String  DELIMITER = ",";

    @FXML
    TableColumn<Stock, Boolean>  checkBoxColumn;

    @FXML
    TableColumn<Stock, LocalDate>  dateColumn;

    @FXML
    TableColumn<Stock, BigDecimal>  priceColumn;

    @FXML
    TableView<Stock>  table;

    @Override // javafx.util.StringConverter
    public String toString(LocalDate object) {
        return object.format(FORMATTER);
    }

    @Override // javafx.util.StringConverter
    public LocalDate fromString(String string) {
        return LocalDate.parse(string, FORMATTER);
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        table.setEditable(true);
        checkBoxColumn.setCellValueFactory(f -> f.getValue().checkedProperty());
        checkBoxColumn.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(checkBoxColumn));
        dateColumn.setCellValueFactory(f -> f.getValue().dateProperty());
        dateColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(this));
        priceColumn.setCellValueFactory(f -> f.getValue().priceProperty());
        ObservableList<Stock> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("stocks.csv");
        try (InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                String[] fields = line.split(DELIMITER);
                BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(fields[2]);
                LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(fields[1], FORMATTER);
                String name = fields[0];
                Stock stock = new Stock(price, date, name);
                items.add(stock);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            items = items.sorted();
            table.setItems(items);
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            throw new RuntimeException(xIo);
        }
    }
}
```

The "model" class, `Stock`

```java
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Stock implements Comparable<Stock> {
    private SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal>  price;
    private SimpleBooleanProperty  checked;
    private SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate>  date;
    private SimpleStringProperty  name;

    public Stock(BigDecimal price, LocalDate date, String name) {
        this.price = new SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal>(this, "price", price);
        this.date = new SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate>(this, "date", date);
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name", name);
        checked = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    }

    public SimpleBooleanProperty checkedProperty() {
        return checked;
    }

    public boolean getChecked() {
        return checked.get();
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean check) {
        checked.set(check);
    }

    public SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate> dateProperty() {
        return date;
    }

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date.get();
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDate ld) {
        date.set(ld);
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal> priceProperty() {
        return price;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price.get();
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal cost) {
        price.set(cost);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Stock o) {
        int result;
        if (o == null) {
            result = 1;
        }
        else {
            if (o.date == null) {
                result = 1;
            }
            else {
                if (o.date.get() == null) {
                    result = 1;
                }
                else {
                    if (date == null) {
                        result = -1;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (date.get() == null) {
                            result = -1;
                        }
                        else {
                            if (date.get().isBefore(o.date.get())) {
                                result = -1;
                            }
                            else if (date.get().isAfter(o.date.get())) {
                                result = 1;
                            }
                            else {
                                result = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

The CSV file, *stocks.csv*

```
first,05-08-2022,1.22
second,03-08-2022,1.35
third,07-08-2022,67.0
last,06-08-2022,4.5
```

- Class `Stock` implements comparable to allow `items` to be sorted *by natural order*. Refer to [default] method `sorted` in interface `javafx.collections.ObservableList`.
- The `TableView` is made editable so as to allow selecting the check boxes.
- Values are read from the CSV file and converted to the appropriate type in order to create `Stock` instances.
- A `StringConverter` is used to both format and parse values in the `date` column.
- Files `stoktabl.fxml` and `stocks.csv` are located in the same folder as file `StockTable.class`
- All above [Java] classes are in the same package (even though I omitted the package statements from the above code.
- Controller classes no longer need to implement interface `javafx.fxml.Initializable`. They may, optionally, declare method `initialize` that takes no parameters and returns `void`.

Here is a screen capture:

[image: screen capture]

Comment: There is a built-in [`LocalDateStringConverter`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.base/javafx/util/converter/LocalDateStringConverter.html), which could be used.

Answer (score 2):

@Abra has [shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73266958/230513) how to effect sorting by implementing `Comparable<Stock>`, and @Dan has [shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73265727/230513) how to leverage [`LocalDate::compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#compareTo(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate)), provided by its implementation of `Comparable<ChronoLocalDate>`. The example below focuses on the benefit of using `LocalDate` directly in your model. In particular, you can simply `add()` the date column to the sort order. As shown in the [`TableView`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) API, a simple binding can restore the original, unsorted order.

[image: Date sort]

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72437984/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72437984/230513
 */
public class LocalDateTest extends Application {

    private record Model(LocalDate date, String name) {}

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle(this.getClass().getName());
        var model = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Model(LocalDate.now().minusDays(1),"Yesterday"),
            new Model(LocalDate.now(), "Today"),
            new Model(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1), "Tommorrow"),
            new Model(LocalDate.now().with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()), "Deadline")
        );
        SortedList sortedList = new SortedList(model);
        var table = new TableView(sortedList);
        sortedList.comparatorProperty().bind(table.comparatorProperty());

        TableColumn<Model, LocalDate> date = new TableColumn<>("Date");
        date.setCellValueFactory(cd -> new SimpleObjectProperty(cd.getValue().date()));
        table.getColumns().add(date);
        table.getSortOrder().add(date);

        TableColumn<Model, String> name = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        name.setCellValueFactory(cd -> new SimpleStringProperty(cd.getValue().name()));
        table.getColumns().add(name);

        StackPane root = new StackPane(table);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As it has been pointed out in the comments, I second @dan1st's suggestion of using a `LocalDate` instead of a plain `String` to represent a date and order your `Stock` instances according to their `dateRN`.

However, If for some reason you're actually bound to a `String` implementation, then you could resort to a `LocalDate` conversion within the `compareTo` definition and still implement the `Comparable` interface in your `Stock` class.

Here is a rough implementation:

```
public class Stock implements Comparable<Stock> {
    private String ticker;
    private Double price;
    private String dateRN;

    public Stock() {
        this.dateRN = "";
    }

    public Stock(String ticker, Double price, String dateRN) {
        this.ticker = ticker;
        this.price = price;
        this.dateRN = dateRN;
    }

    //... getters, setters & rest of class implementation

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Stock o) {
        return LocalDate.parse(dateRN, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")).compareTo(LocalDate.parse(o.dateRN, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Stock{dateRN='" + dateRN + '\'' +'}';
    }
}
```

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Stock> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
                new Stock("test1", 1.5, "05-08-2022"),
                new Stock("test2", 2.5, "03-08-2022"),
                new Stock("test3", 3.5, "07-08-2022"),
                new Stock("test4", 4.5, "06-08-2022")
        ));

        System.out.println(list);

        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println("\n" + list);
    }
}
```

Here is a link to test the code above:

https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/tLI

##### Output

Original and sorted output based on the sample data of your question.

```
[Stock{dateRN='05-08-2022'}, Stock{dateRN='03-08-2022'}, Stock{dateRN='07-08-2022'}, Stock{dateRN='06-08-2022'}]

[Stock{dateRN='03-08-2022'}, Stock{dateRN='05-08-2022'}, Stock{dateRN='06-08-2022'}, Stock{dateRN='07-08-2022'}]
```