# Adding individual item to a TableView?

Tags: javafx

I have started using JavaFX for a few weeks. Here is a code snap of a TableView

```
@FXML protected void handleSubmitButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    log.debug("handleSubmitButtonAction");
    service.save(new InputText(inputText.getText()));

    List<OutputData> outputDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    service.getAll().forEach(e -> outputDataList.add(new OutputData(e)));
    ObservableList<OutputData> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(outputDataList);
    outputView.setItems(list);

    inputText.setText("");
}
```

What it does is that

- Create a new entry
- Save it to DB
- Fetch all entries from DB
- Create TableView row data for each entry
- Create an ObservableList with all of the row data
- Add the list to the TableView

That certainly isn't effective. Is a way to add a newly created entry directly to the TableView?

Comment: Just create the row data only for the new entry and pass it to `outputView.getItems().add(…)`. Create and post a [mre] if you can’t get it to work.

Comment: Thanks. And interesting! That bypasses the data type designed for a row in the TableView and ObservableList. The property in the <PropertyValueFactory property="<property>" /> needs to match the data, but not the data type designed for the ViewTable.

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re saying at all there. The table view is displaying `OutputData` objects. Assuming everything is set up correctly, the only thing you can pass to `outputView.getItems().add(…)` is an `OutputData` instance. You should not use `PropertyValueFactory` in modern applications: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/72437983/2189127

Comment: What I tried to say is that the approach omits the data type, which its properties are the SimpleStringProperty type, defined for a row of the TableView. And ObservableList is not needed either (BTW what it is for originally?) A column in the FXML file is coded as:             

<TableColumn text="Input Text">
                <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="inputText" />
                </cellValueFactory>
</TableColumn>

How to map the property if PropertyValueFactory isn't used? Sorry, I am a beginner for JavaFX.

Comment: *"the approach omits the data type"*. This doesn't make sense. Java is strongly typed. Every object has a runtime type, every variable has a compile-time type and the types must match the expected parameter type at compile time. The `add(...)` method will require an object of type `OutputData`; if you pass the wrong type, it's a compile error. *"ObservableList is not needed either"*. No, it is absolutely needed. Look at the docs for the return type of `TableView.getItems()`. *"How to map the property if PropertyValueFactory isn't used?"* See link in previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do.

1. Have `service.save(new InputText(inputText.getText()));` return a
   true if the data was saved to the DB and false otherwise.
2. If true is returned, I would then add the data to the `TableView`
   using `outputView.getItems().add(inputText.getText());`
3. If false is retured, I would use an `Alert` to let the user know
   that the data was not added to the DB.

Comment: The output data isn't the same as the input text. I did something on the same track.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://github.com/sedj601/SQLitePersonTableViewExample). Hopefully, it will help.