# JavaFX TableView commit change to object field without setOnEditCommit()

Tags: javafx, tableview

Can TableView commit changes to generic fields like String or Integer without extra step with setOnEditCommit?

Currently I use such structure:

```
@FXML
TableColumn<User, String> _tableStateUsername;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
   _tableStateUsername.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<User, String>forTableColumn(new DefaultStringConverter()));
   _tableStateUsername.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("username"));
   _tableStateUsername.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<User, String>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<User, String> event) {
            event.getRowValue().setUsername(event.getNewValue());
        }
    });
```

and it works fine, but I feel that it can be simplified (without using SimpleString)

I tried binding Value factory to field but no luck:

```
_tableStateUsername.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> Bindings.select(cellData.getValue(), "username"));
```

Is there any way to make cell set NewValue to bound field automatically?

Comment: Assuming you are following the JavaFX properties pattern, this should work automatically, without the call to `setOnEditCommit(…)`.

Comment: Perhaps related: [avoid using `PropertyValueFactory`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72437983/why-should-i-avoid-using-propertyvaluefactory-in-javafx-and-what-should-i-use-i)

Comment: as @James_D already noted: yes, actually that's the default behaviour (provided the data class is implemented appropriately) - if the references don't help, provide a [mcve] please ..