# Error in setting cell values for a TableView column

Tags: java, javafx

I'm a newbie to JavaFX (still learning) and I'm currently in the topic of TableViews. I have followed this one particular YouTube video where he made a program about inserting cells to a TableView and it worked real smoothly for him. I followed along and all seems great with no errors in the editor only to be met with an error at runtime. The error displays:

---

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1135)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:893)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Mako/Documents/Programming/Eclipse-workspace2/JavaFXTable/bin/application/Scene1.fxml

    at javafx.fxml@21.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml@21.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2700)
    at javafx.fxml@21.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2563)
    at javafx.fxml@21.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3376)
    at javafx.fxml@21.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3332)
    at javafx.fxml@21.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3300)
    at javafx.fxml@21.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3272)
    at javafx.fxml@21.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3248)
    at javafx.fxml@21.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3241)
    at JavaFXTable/application.Main.start(Main.java:16)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.setCellValueFactory(javafx.util.Callback)" because "this.name" is null
    at JavaFXTable/application.Scene1Controller.initialize(Scene1Controller.java:32)
    at javafx.fxml@21.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2670)
    ... 17 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

---

These are the codes I have in my current package, all contained within a single package.
**Main.java**

```
package application;
    
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Scene1.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Scene1Controller.java**

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

public class Scene1Controller implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Food, String> name;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Food, Integer> price;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Food> table;

    ObservableList<Food> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Food("Pizza", 10),
            new Food("IcedCream", 5)
            );
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Food, String>("name"));
        price.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Food, Integer>("price"));
        
        table.setItems(list);
    }
    
    
    
}
```

**Food.java**

```
package application;

public class Food {

    String name;
    int price;
    
    public Food(String name, int price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    
}
```

**Scene1.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/21" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Scene1Controller">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="table" layoutX="200.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="name" prefWidth="75.0" text="name" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="price" prefWidth="75.0" text="price" />
        </columns>
         <columnResizePolicy>
            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
         </columnResizePolicy>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Hope someone can help, have a great day!

I tried following along other videos with the same topic to no avail.

Comment: That all looks correct. Make sure you have saved the FXML file, and perhaps clean and rebuild the project. If you comment out the three lines of code in the `initialize(...)` method, do you see the table columns with their headers?

Comment: I can't see where things might be going wrong, but what happens if you create setters in `Food`? The `FX:ID` looked good to me, so I am not really sure.

Comment: To do that, don't the fields in Food need to be defined as Properties with the correct JavaFX bean methods defined.  In particular don't you need a method called nameProperty() that returns a StringProperty?

Comment: Also, isn't PropertyValueFactory virtually depricated at this point?  Use a lambda instead?

Comment: Off-topic: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72437983/why-should-i-avoid-using-propertyvaluefactory-in-javafx, and also the note in the [documentation for `Initializable`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html)

Comment: @DaveB `PropertyValueFactory` will fall back to using the standard JavaBean `getName()` method if no appropriate property accessor exists ([see docs](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html)), though I agree the use of that class is outdated.

Comment: @James_D it launches successfully without any errors when I try to remove the line of code inside the **initialize()** method
image: https://i.imgur.com/Pc4GYqd.png

Comment: @jewelsea so I tried modifying the `module-info.java` file by adding a `javafx.base` to the `opens application to` section and it worked successfully!

Answer (score 1):

#### Advice: Don't use `PropertyValueFactory` at all

There is **NO** reason to prefer to use `PropertyValueFactory` instead of the superior lambda-based solution when using Java 9+ (e.g. any modern Java version).  See:

- [Why should I avoid using PropertyValueFactory in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72437983/why-should-i-avoid-using-propertyvaluefactory-in-javafx)

#### Opening your package to `javafx.base` for reflection

To allow `PropertyValueFactory` to work in a modular application and as confirmed by the asker in comments:

> I tried modifying the `module-info.java` file by adding a `javafx.base` to the `opens application to` section and it worked successfully.

Your code also worked fine for me (the table showed and populated as expected), as long as I had the appropriate `opens` clause in my `module-info.java`.

If I modify the FXML you provided, by deleting the attribute `fx:id="name"` from the FXML, it will fail with the same error message that you noted in your question.  Otherwise, it will fail as below until the `module-info.java` is set the correct value.

From the [`PropertyValueFactory`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) javadoc:

> **Deploying an Application as a Module**
>
> If the referenced class is in a named module, then it must be
> reflectively accessible to the `javafx.base` module. A class is
> reflectively accessible if the module opens the containing package to
> at least the javafx.base module. Otherwise the
> call(`TableColumn.CellDataFeatures`) method will log a warning and
> return null.
>
> For example, if the `Person` class is in the `com.foo` package in the
> `foo.app` module, the `module-info.java` might look like this:
>
> ```
> module foo.app {
>     opens com.foo to javafx.base; 
> }
> ```
>
> Alternatively, a class is reflectively accessible if the module exports the containing package
> unconditionally.

The module access issue creates a warning message:

```
WARNING: Can not retrieve property 'name' in PropertyValueFactory: javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory@109ad50a with provided class type: class application.Food
```

And a stack trace with the following cause:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: module javafx.base cannot access class application.Food (in module <your module>) because module <your module> does not open application to javafx.base
```