Filtering a tableview
I have a program that uses javafx and springboot. I have a table that has two columns - a code column and a description column. The end user can type within a search textfield and the column filters based on what text is being typed.
Previously I was able to use the FilterList function to use for the filtering however since implementing springboot I haven't been able to get this to work properly.
DiagnosisCode.java
@Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        codeCol.setCellValueFactory((new PropertyValueFactory<>("Code")));
        descripCol.setCellValueFactory((new PropertyValueFactory<>("Description")));
        newDiagCodeTable.getColumns().setAll(codeCol, descripCol);
        newDiagCodeTable.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(diagnosisService.findAll()));
        sortData();

    }

   @FXML
    public void sortData(){
        FilteredList<IDiagnosisModel> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(listView, b -> true);
        searchCodes.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            filteredData.setPredicate(diagnosisCode -> {
                if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                    return true;
                }
                String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();

                if (diagnosisCode.getDiagnosisDescription().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                    return true;
                } else if (diagnosisCode.getDiagnosisCode().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                    return true;

                } else return false;
            });
        });
        SortedList<IDiagnosisModel> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);
        sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(newDiagCodeTable.comparatorProperty());
        newDiagCodeTable.setItems(sortedData);
    }


I have tried to use the findByCode(String code). For example I had setup a setOnKeyPressed event that would get the text of what was typed in and use the findByCode() function to take in the String of what has been typed. This didn't work.
Is there a springboot specific method that I am missing?
DiagnosisCode.java
  @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        sortData();

        codeCol.setCellValueFactory((new PropertyValueFactory<>("Code")));
        descripCol.setCellValueFactory((new PropertyValueFactory<>("Description")));
        newDiagCodeTable.getColumns().setAll(codeCol, descripCol);
        newDiagCodeTable.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(diagnosisService.findAll()));

        this.searchCodes.setOnKeyPressed(keyEvent -> {
            String name = this.searchCodes.getText().trim();
            diagnosisService.findByCode(name);
        });


    }


In sortData() you have newDiagCodeTable.setItems(sortedData); then in your update DiagnosisCode.initialize you have newDiagCodeTable.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(diagnosisService.findAll())); -> that will replace the sorted filtered item list with a new list with all of the items -> your sorting and filtering will never work.  There may be other issues I didn't check, but it seems like a simple logic error rather than some fundamental issue with springboot or your JavaFX sorting and filtering implementation, especially if it worked before you made changes.

If you continue to have issues, you may want to test this by providing a hard coded data version of diagnosisService.  Then you could provide a [mcve] in the question (which would not need SpringBoot at all) that replicates the issue via copy and paste with no change or addition -> that would allow you to get some debugging assistance if you need it.

Simply calling diagnosisService.findByCode(...) won't do anything unless you do something with the list that is returned. You need to decide if you are going to filter the table on the client side (with the JavaFX code) or on the database side (using the repository methods).

Off-topic: don't use PropertyValueFactory. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72437983/why-should-i-avoid-using-propertyvaluefactory-in-javafx-and-what-should-i-use-i.

Off-topic: don't use low-level event handlers (such as onKeyPressed) with high-level controls (such as TextFields). Register a listener with the textProperty() instead.

Off-topic: is sortData() an event handler method (registered with a control in the FXML file)? If so, you should not be adding listeners to the textProperty() there, because you will end up with multiple listeners executing the same functionality. (And if not, obviously, it should not be annotated @FXML.)

@James_D - no its not an event handler method. The filter logic is all within the initalizer method. It sounds like I'm trying to filter the data using BOTH the javafx code and the repository methods.

If it's not an event handler method, it shouldn't be annotated @FXML.

What are you actually trying to achieve with the key event handler on searchCodes? What is that code supposed to do?

That's true! I didn't even catch that I had put @FXML as the annotation on the method. I actually just figured this out. What's happening now is that when a user starts typing in a word the table at the bottom filters and sorts to the code for selection. That way they don't have to scroll down the entire list.. I'll update the main question with the solution. Thank you for your help!

This was a logic error.
Below is the solution:
codeCol.setCellValueFactory((new PropertyValueFactory<>("Code")));
    descripCol.setCellValueFactory((new PropertyValueFactory<>("Description")));
    newDiagCodeTable.getColumns().setAll(codeCol, descripCol);

    listView.addAll(diagnosisService.findAll());
    newDiagCodeTable.setItems(listView);


    FilteredList<IDiagnosisModel> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(listView, b -> true);
    searchCodes.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        filteredData.setPredicate(diagnosisCode -> {
            if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                return true;
            }
            String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();

            if (diagnosisCode.getDiagnosisDescription().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true;
            } else if (diagnosisCode.getDiagnosisCode().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true;

            } else return false;
        });
    });
    SortedList<IDiagnosisModel> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);
    sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(newDiagCodeTable.comparatorProperty());
    newDiagCodeTable.setItems(sortedData);

I created listview to hold the codes found within the findAll() function, then created the filter and sort and added it to the table.
